# Get edges info in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, graph-databases

I am using SQL Server GraphDB.
My intention is to get all edges info inside the result.

The following line only return single row of the edges info, but I am expecting it to return multiple row info from the edge if there exist multiple edges. (in this case A-> E has multiple edges)

How can this be achieve?

Fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=daafe09fdde04fbcd650160f6fb3c221

```
SELECT
    username, StartNode, [Edges Path], FinalNode, Levels
FROM (
    SELECT 
        P1.username, 
        P1.username as StartNode, 
        STRING_AGG(p2.userName + ', ' + ISNULL(Follow.Count1, '0'), '->')  WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Edges Path],
        LAST_VALUE(P2.userName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS FinalNode,
        COUNT(P2.userName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS Levels
    FROM
        Person P1,
        Person FOR PATH P2,
        Follow FOR PATH Follow
    WHERE 
        MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(P1(-(Follow)->P2)+))
 ) AS Q
 WHERE Q.FinalNode = 'C'
```

Result:

| username | StartNode | Edges Path | FinalNode | Levels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | E | C, 0 | C | 1 |
| A | A | E, 1->C, 0 | C | 2 (wrong) |
| B | B | E, 0->C, 0 | C | 2 |
| C | C | A, 0->E, 1->C, 0 | C | 3 (wrong) |
| F | F | B, 0->E, 0->C, 0 | C | 3 |

Expectation

| username | StartNode | Edges Path | FinalNode | Levels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | E | C, 0 | C | 1 |
| A | A | E, 1, 2->C, 0 | C | 2 (correct) |
| B | B | E, 0->C, 0 | C | 2 |
| C | C | A, 0->E, 1, 2->C, 0 | C | 3 (correct) |
| F | F | B, 0->E, 0->C, 0 | C | 3 |

Comment: So you want all the paths that are the same length as the SHORTEST_PATH?  And the results are very hard to read.

Comment: Seems you have not just multiple paths, but multiple *identical* paths. Not sure if GraphDB even supports that, although can't find any docs to the contrary

Comment: @Charlieface yes correct. I have multiple edges of same start node and end node. How to deal with that?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have multiple edges of same start and end node, and i want to display all of that. how could it be done